# Decoding content:encoden XML Content in a ios app

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, rss

Im making a iPhone application where i have make a RSS reader. 
I am showing Content:encoded in the tableview where all the feeds are shown.

My problem is when i run the application this is in front of all the content in the feeds

is there anybody there know how to decode the XML code from the feed?

in advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi Peter You need to parse the XML to uncover its contents.See the following link for a tutorial
[XML Parsing tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/johnse4/ios-xml-parsingtutorial-7880169) . Try TBXML library for parsing. Its efficient in my point of view [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides.html)